# Short-circuiting an np.all with a nested np.less for large array comparisons in numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numba

In my current code (see MWE) I have a bottleneck where I perform `np.all` with a nested `np.less` for large 2D arrays. I know that if there is a single `false` value in `np.less` we can stop checking because the rest of the values in the index the code will evaluate to `false` (since I am **AND**-ing all values in a single index of a given dimension together).

Is there a way with numba or numpy where I can exploit this "early exit/short-circuit" condition to generate a meaningful speed-up in this calculation?

The second to last line in the MWE is what I'm trying to speed-up. Please note `N` and `M` can be very large, but only very few comparisons will actually evaluate to `true`.

```
import numpy as np

N = 10000
M = 10 # Reduced to small value to show that sometimes the comparisons evaluate to 'True'

array = np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=10.0, size=(N, M))
comparison_array = np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=10.0, size=(M))

# Can we apply an early exit condition on this?
mask = np.all(np.less(array, comparison_array), axis=-1)

print(f"Number of 'True' comparisons: {np.sum(mask)}")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's `numba` version, developed enough to work, not necessarily optimized:

```
@numba.njit
def foo(arr, carr):
    N, M = arr.shape
    mask = np.ones(N, dtype=np.bool_)
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(M):
            if arr[i,j]>=carr[j]:
                mask[i]=False
                break
    return mask
```

Testing:

```
In [178]: np.sum(foo(array, comparison_array))
Out[178]: 2
In [179]: np.sum(np.all(np.less(array, comparison_array), axis=1))
Out[179]: 2
```

timing:

```
In [180]: timeit np.sum(foo(array, comparison_array))
155 µs ± 6.36 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [181]: timeit np.sum(np.all(np.less(array, comparison_array), axis=1))
451 µs ± 5.19 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

That's a decent improvement.

Comment: Woah, that's a great improvement! What things should I focus on to build on your solution to further optimize it?